# LoadingRow in DataGrid in MVVM WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like no more to have code behind, then I jumped to MVVM and now i have stacked on DataGrid on LoadingRow for incrementing the index numbers of contents from DataGrid

CODES Behind.

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
  e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

View-specific logic like this should still always be implemented in the view or the control. It's not the resonsibility of the view model to number the actual rows.

It's another story if you want to assign each data object a unique number. You should then add a property to your data object and bind to this in the `DataGrid`.

But if you simply want to display the row numbers for the rows that the `DataGrid` generates, it's perfectly fine to handle the `LoadingRow` event as suggested [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/08/18/right-aligned-row-numbers-datagridrowheader-wpf/).

MVVM is not about eliminating view-related code from the views - it's mainly about separation of concerns.